# Determine a known battery's instantaneous capacity through voltage? / voltage's relation to capacity

Tags: voltage, charger, charge, capacity

Is it possible to approximate a battery's current (the "right now" kind of current) capacity, given its absolute capacity and a voltage measurement?

An example:
I have a 1s 260mAh LiPo that is at 3.75 volts. I must charge it to 3.85 volts to store it, but I'd like to have a rough approximation of how long that should take.

I know that I can take a capacity in Ah or mAh and divide it by the charge rate (for my charger, 0.2A), which would give me the time in hours to charge that capacity (In perfect simulation). However, to do apply this to the example, I would obviously need to know the instantaneous capacity of the battery, to get the amount of mAh that I need to calculate for.

Another way to word the question: what is the relation between a battery's voltage and its capacity?

Comment: Yes but not very accurately.

Comment: The relationship between a battery's voltage and its capacity is not very reliable. This has been discussed here many times.

Comment: Connecting a new but useless lead-acid battery to the charger yesterday, the voltage shot-up to about 17v. Over the course of the remainder of the day, it continued to drop until I disconnected it and it read about 10. The initial voltage was about 5 or 6v..

Comment: If you know the voltage, unfortunately the actual capacity is different for every battery.  Software could run an experiment to map the behavior of one battery.  Unfortunately, it changes with age, temperature, overloads, and with the number of charge cycles, so the table you built from the "calibration charging" wouldn't be very reliable.

Comment: It's a forever-in-study problem. For some battery it can be done reliably, for other one (like lithium primaries) it's not possible. As an alternative they do charge counters with keep track of how much has entered and exited the battery to do a balance of the remaining charge

Comment: Useful search term : coulomb counting.

Answer (score 1):

There is memory or hysteresis in voltage due to a double layer effect.  There is also slight variations in polymer chemistry in particular Fe or iron that affect the relationship.

- AFAIK 3.7 is 90% and 3.0 is 10% as a resting voltage.
- ESR affects voltage drop or rise due current x ESR and this rises faster as SoC drops near and below 10%.
- Peukert’s Law applies to battery efficiency, partly due to memory effects on ESR.
- The 0.5C is the best trade off for speed and storage efficiency yet 1C is often used still others will use up a battery in 30 minutes or 40C.

So try my estimate and confirm with your datasheet.

Graph 3.0 to 3.7V as 10% to 90%
Then use the recommended CC, CV and %CC cutoff value to determine new capacity from datasheet. E.g. 100% @ 1C will take longer than 1h on new cells but less time on aged cells as the capacity is reduced.  Keep records and serialize each cells charge and discharge times. Learn from your experience with use and brands.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to approximate a battery's current (the "right now"
> kind of current) capacity, given its absolute capacity and a voltage
> measurement?

Yes. The relationship between resting voltage and capacity of a Lipo cell is non-linear and varies depending on the chemistry. To get an accurate value you would have to measure the capacity of *your* battery at various voltages. However most have a similar curve, so if you only need an approximate value you could use other's test data such as [this](https://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showpost.php?p=3272601&postcount=11):-

```
This is a test I did for capacity vs. Resting voltage.

72 degree pack and room temp.
The (999mAh) pack was discharged each time at 1C, to a 3v per cell cutoff.
Then I added a fixed percentage of charge, and measured the resting voltage after 12 hours.
Next I discharged the pack and verified the percentage of capacity.
At the end of all testing I charged the pack fully and did a accuracy / repeatability test.
The repeatability of the test was over 98%.

4.20v = 100%
4.03v = 76%
3.86v = 52%
3.83v = 42%
3.79v = 30%
3.70v = 11%
3.6?v = 0%
```

or [this](http://www.thejumperwire.com/science/lipo-characteristics-part-2-electrical-properties/):-

[image]

The graph needs some interpretation because it shows nominal capacity, not usable capacity. If we subtract the last 10% (because at 10% the cell has practically nothing left) we get ~25% capacity at 3.75 V and 60% at 3.85 V.